# Turning bump off entirely temporarily in eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, bump

Is there a way of turning off bump entirely for a temporary time then turn it back on in Eevee? When I use bump nodes and noise detail things gets a bit laggy in material preview.

Comment: In the Shading editor you can mute a noodle (connecting line) by dragging across it with Ctrl-Alt-RMB. Re-enable it in the same way. I'm not sure whether you need the Node Wrangler addon enabled to use that hotkey combination. - I always have it enabled here.

Comment: @JohnEason it’s not CTRL+ALT+RMB that’s the knife tool to disconnect. it’s the M key while selecting the node. And I want to mute all the bump like a button instead of muting each node.

Comment: CTRL-RMB is the combination to **cut** a noodle but CTRL+ALT+RMB (which seems to be undocumented) **does** mute a noodle without disconnecting it. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0esPcjbhE04) short YT video! The M key just mutes a node and lets the input straight through to the output. I just gave the mute noodle option in case it might help. I doubt you can mute all bump nodes without using python.

Comment: True, the reason why it maybe undocumented is because it’s in the node wrangler article in the blender manual as most node tricks/shortcuts come with node wrangler. I just tried out CTRL+ALT+RMB and it worked. I thought it was knife tool though- I guess I can try that out! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Bludus As I understood your question, you want to mute multiple bump nodes instead of each node separately... all in one material or in different materials at the same time? Because I do not see how Ctrl+Alt+RMB helps with multiple materials... and if it is just one material, why was using M to mute the nodes not an option?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I wanted different material have bump off at the same time, kind of like a collection in the oultliner

Comment: @Bludus So that shortcut was not yet the solution? Then I misread your comment, sorry.

Comment: No not yet. I could always find another way basically but thanks for helping me anyways